# Running Tahiti: Aglet Viewer

Tags: java, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception, agent

Working on (aglets-2.0.1.zip)

I'm trying to run Tahiti and I've got this error. It is as it showing in the picture

[image]

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException aglet66
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply include public folder in classpath as:

for Linux:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/ravi/Desktop/dc/aglets2.5-alpha/public/:$CLASSPATH
```

For windows:

```
set CLASSPATh=%CLASSPATH%;C:\....\aglets2.5-alpha\public\
```